# Estoy tratando de sumar dos inputs

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentando sumar dos inputs y no se puedo.

Estoy tratando de imprimirlo en la consola para luego pasarlo al otro input el resultado pero
cuando trato de sumar los dos inputs me da este código en la consola "NaN"

```js
function Suma() {
    var suma = parseInt(document.getElementsByTagName("Sumar").value);
    var suma2 = parseInt(document.getElementsByTagName("Sumar2").value);
    var resultado = parseInt(suma) + parseInt(suma2);
    console.log(resultado); 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <span >
            <input type="text" style="width: 65px;" name="Sumar" >
            <input type="text" style="width: 65px;" name="Sumar2" >
            <button type="button" onclick="Suma()">Sumar</button>
            <input type="text" style="width: 65px;" name="ResultadoSuma" placeholder="Resultado">
        </span> 
    </div>
    
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La verdad no logro determinar tu error. Creo que es porque tomas los valores de tus inputs a través de [getElementsTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) y esto retorna un array de colecciones de los atributos con esos tags. Así que deberías hacer algo como: `document.getElementsByTagName("Sumar")[0].value` y ahí sí podrías acceder a su valor, pero es solo por intuición lo que te digo. Igual te dejo la solución a tu problema en el siguiente snippet:

```js
const value1 = document.getElementById('value1');
const value2 = document.getElementById('value2');
const sumar = document.getElementById('sumar');
let resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');

sumar.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let v1 = parseInt(value1.value)
  let v2 = parseInt(value2.value)
  
  console.log(v1+v2)
  
  resultado.value = v1 + v2;
});
```

```html
<input id="value1">
<input id="value2">
<button id="sumar">Sumar</button>
<input id="resultado" value="">
```

Comment: Gracias! pensaba que era lo mismo si usaba el "name" o "id"

Comment: No, no son iguales en realidad. Siempre estate atento a ese tipo de cosas. Igual fue un placer ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que identifiques a tus inputs mediante `id` de la forma:

```
<input type="text" style="width: 65px;" id="Sumar" >
```

Y en JavaScript los leas mediante:

```
document.getElementById("Sumar").value
```

De esa forma tu código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <span >
            <input type="text" style="width: 65px;" id="Sumar" >
            <input type="text" style="width: 65px;" id="Sumar2" >
            <button type="button" onclick="Suma()">Sumar</button>
            <input type="text" style="width: 65px;" id="ResultadoSuma" placeholder="Resultado">
        </span> 
    </div>
    
    <script>
    function Suma() {
        
    var suma = parseInt(document.getElementById("Sumar").value);
    var suma2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("Sumar2").value);
    var resultado = parseInt(suma) + parseInt(suma2);
    document.getElementById("ResultadoSuma").value = resultado;
    console.log(resultado); 
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás usando el selector equivocado, `getElementsByTagName()` es para seleccionar elementos por el nombre de etiqueta por ejemplo `div` o `input`, lo que debes usar es `getElementsByName`, si quieres seleccionar por medio del atributo `name`, por otro lado, si usas `getElementsByName`, esto retorna una colección de elementos que tengan ese `name`, lo recomendable es usar `getElementById` que solo retorna un elemento, te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
function Suma() {
    var suma = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("Sumar")[0].value);
    var suma2 = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("Sumar2")[0].value);
    
    var suma_id = parseInt(document.getElementById("Sumar").value);
    var suma2_id = parseInt(document.getElementById("Sumar2").value);
    
    var resultado = parseInt(suma) + parseInt(suma2);
    var resultado2 = parseInt(suma_id) + parseInt(suma2_id);
    console.log('Este resultado es usando getElementByName: '+resultado);
    console.log('Este resultado es usando getElementById: '+resultado2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <span >
            <input type="text" style="width: 65px;" name="Sumar" id="Sumar">
            <input type="text" style="width: 65px;" name="Sumar2" id="Sumar2">
            <button type="button" onclick="Suma()">Sumar</button>
            <input type="text" style="width: 65px;" name="ResultadoSuma" placeholder="Resultado">
        </span> 
    </div>
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias! no pensé que la solución solo era eso, ando aprendiendo entonces estoy practicando y cosas así, Gracias! nuevamente

Answer (score 0):

**Problemas:**

1. La funcion [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) la estas empleando incorrectamente, porque en realidad no estas seleccionando el "name" del `input`, sino un `tag`(un elemento html como: `<input>, <p>, <ul>, etc`), como dice su nombre "**ByTagName**".
2. Si quisieras seleccionar aun por el "nombre", deberias utilizar la funcion [getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName), que esta si selecciona los elementos por "nombre".

   En el siguiente ejemplo estoy seleccionando el valor de los inputs por "name", si te das cuenta pongo un "`[0].value`", esto es porque la funcion retorna coleccion de lista de todos los "name" que existen

```js
function Valores() {
  var input1 = document.getElementsByName('Sumar')[0].value;
  var input2 = document.getElementsByName('Sumar2')[0].value;
  console.log(input1 + ' - ' + input2);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" style="width: 65px;" name="Sumar">
<input type="text" style="width: 65px;" name="Sumar2">

<button onclick="Valores()">Valores</button>
```

**Solucion:**

Lo recomendable y optimo es que selecciones por `id`, utilizando [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) para que obtengas el valor del elemento "input" y hacer tus respectivas operaciones

```js
function Suma() {
  var suma = parseInt(document.getElementById("input1").value);
  var suma2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("input2").value);
  var resultado = suma + suma2;
  document.getElementById("Resultado").value = resultado;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <span>
            <input type="text" style="width: 65px;" name="Sumar" id="input1">
            <input type="text" style="width: 65px;" name="Sumar2" id="input2">
            <button type="button" onclick="Suma()">Sumar</button>
            <input type="text" style="width: 65px;" name="ResultadoSuma" placeholder="Resultado" id="Resultado">
        </span>
  </div>

  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Extra**

Ademas de lo anterior dicho, veo tambien que utilizas 2 veces `parseInt`, lo cual esta mal, ya que con solo una vez basta